# Coded ui test result mdf not generated

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests

I have visual studio ultimate 2012 with update 3 installed

I created a coded ui project and ran some tests but the TestResult folder only contains the html results of these tests. I require the mdf database file to keep track of my results.

Is ther some way I can get the mdf test result file to appear? Do I need to create a settings file or change a value in QTAgent file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Update 3 of Visual Studio, I removed the update and repaired Visual Studio 2012 and the file is now being generated correctly.

Will be reporting this problem to Microsoft.